# Proper way to add packages to component scan in Grails 3

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

I declared several @Components in src/groovy/my/package of a grails 3.1.10 plugin and added the package name to the component scan by adding the following in grails-app/init/application.groovy:

```
 @Override
Collection<String> packageNames() {
    super.packageNames() + ['package.from.plugin']
}
```

It works well as long as I am running the plugin itself. When I include my plugin by adding it in the build.gradle of my application:

```
compile project(':my-plugin')
```

and run the application, the beans declared in my-plugin do not get wired properly anymore, they cannot be found.

**What is the proper way to add custom Components/Beans from Grails Plugin to Grails application component scan?**

Answer (score 3):

Custom components should be declared in plugin declaration (pluginName.groovy inside src/base.package) inside

```
Closure doWithSpring() {{->
    xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"


    context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'your.package') {
        context.'include-filter'(
                type:       'annotation',
                expression: Component.canonicalName)
    }
}}
```

this will make all Components declared with annotation in your.package available in spring context, also in the main application.

Application class inside grails-app/conf/init/application.groovy does runs only when plugin is being run standalone, outside of the main application context.